# Magento2 How can get the Attributes based on the Attribute Set Id or Attribute Set Name

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

In Magento2, How can get the all (product) Attributes based on the Attribute Set Id or Attribute Set Name in the Custom Product List Page.

Comment: On product page?

Comment: No, In Custom Product list Page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Code:

```
    $attributeSetId = 20;//your_attributeSetId
    $attributeSet = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
    $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($attributeSetId);
    $attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName(); 
    $attributeGroupCollection = $this->objectManager->get ( 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Group' )->getCollection ();
    $attributeGroupCollection->addFieldToFilter ( 'attribute_group_name', $attribute_set_name ); 
    $attributeGroupCollection->addFieldToFilter ( 'attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId );
    $attributeGroupId = '';
    foreach ( $attributeGroupCollection as $attributeGroup ) {
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeGroup->getId ();
        break;
    }
    $attributeCollection = $this->objectManager->get ( 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute' )->getCollection ();
    $attributeCollection->setAttributeSetFilter ( $attributeSetId );
    $attributeCollection->setAttributeGroupFilter ( $attributeGroupId );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attributeCollection->getData());
```

Answer (score 5):

you can make use of the Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeManagementInterface

```
$attributeSetId = 20;//your_attributeSetId
$productAttributesManagement = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeManagementInterface');
$productAttributes = $productAttributesManagement->getAttributes($attributeSetId);
```

Please note that you should not be using the object manager directly. This is just for demonstration